# Button in PowerPoint that only works in presentation / slideshow

Tags: vba, button, activex, powerpoint

I am creating a presentation and I wish to create a button that works inside the presentation but also outside the presentation/slideshow. I wanted some unique things so I basically used a label as a button instead of a button, because I didn't want a frame around it and I didn't want to spend the extra 10 seconds in changing it around more or less. The button is working fine while within presentations but outside if I click it I only select the label itself.

[image: is how it is working inside the presentation]
[image: is what happens when I try to click it ouside the presentation]

I tried changing the type of button but it didn't work.

I would like the button to work inside the presentation and outside of it.

Comment: The simple answer:  You can't do this. ActiveX controls like labels/buttons etc only work while in slideshow view. You could use RibbonX code in your PPTM file to add tabs/groups/buttons to the Ribbon; these could call the same routines from normal view as your buttons call from slideshow view (though you might need slight variations to account for the different views)

Comment: Is there any other way other than RibbonX that this could be done? Here is an example very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish from a colleague/friend, at first I thought it was something easy or not too hard but now I think he might've just faked it for the recording somehow because it looks a bit too complicated.https://vimeo.com/user95127376/review/317378703/a5e680b00b

As you can see on the video the label or button on the right is clicked directly. While on normal view, it is very strange.

Comment: Vimeo says "Sorry, we couldn’t find that page" when I click your link. Want to give it another try?